# Map variables not usable in Scala Play HTML template

Tags: html, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have the following code in one of my Play .scala.html templates:

```
@formats.map(format => {
  <div id="@format">
    {format}
  </div>
})
```

`formats` is a `Seq` of enumerations. The divs are created, with the proper "format" content (each contains a different format string), however, the ids are never set correctly. The id of each div is literally set to "@format", like this:

```
<div id="@format">
  OneOfTheFormats
</div>
<div id="@format">
  AnotherFormat
</div>
```

I've tried making the code `<div id="{format}">`, `<div id={format}>`, and `<div id=@format>` with no luck. It's odd, because I have done similar things in my other templates, but perhaps it's not working because of the special `map` case... maybe because `format` is a created argument, and not passed into the template?

**UPDATE:**

I tried the following, as someone below suggested:

```
@{
    def createDiv(f: String) = {
        <div id="@f">
            {f}
        </div>
    }

    formats.map(f => {
        createDiv(f.toString)
    })
}
```

Again, The formats are printed correctly *inside* the div, but the ID is never set. I'm beginning to think this isn't possible. I've also tried `<div id="@f">`, `<div id="{f}">`, and `<div id="@{f}">` with no luck. Oddly enough, in order to print the format inside the div, I have to use `{f}`, and not `@f`. Still struggling here...

**UPDATE 2:**

It works if I do the following: `<div id={f}>` ... no quotes! God damn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
@{
    def createDiv(format: String) = {
        <div id={format}>
            {format}
        </div>
    }

    formats.map(format => {
        createDiv(format.toString)
    })
}
```

Note the enclosed `@{ }` block, and that there are no quotes around the id part of `<div id={format}>`.

**UPDATE:**

I ended up doing something a bit cleaner - I used a separate template file. The code looks a bit like this now:

```
@formats.map(f => {
    // do some other stuff
    // render format subview
    formatSubView(f, otherStuff)
})
```

And the sub-view template looks like the following:

```
@(f: theFormatEnum,
  otherStuff: lotsOfOtherStuff)

<div id="@f">
    <img src="@{routes.Assets.at("images/" + f + ".png")}"/>
    // etc, etc
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there are some limitations for declaring new variables in new templates, but you can use such a workaround:

```
@createDiv(format: String) = {
  <div id="@format">
    @format
  </div>
}
```

And use it in your code like this:

```
@formats.map(format => {
  createDiv(format.toString)
})
```

This worked for me. Hope this solution suits you.

Comment: Hmmm... this is probably close, but I'm having trouble with it: I get a `not found: value createDiv` error, despite having defined `@createDiv` right above `@formats.map`. Very odd - I'll keep fiddling with it.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that there is name collision then you use "format" as a variable name probably because of String.format, try with different name

```
@formats.map{f =>
<div id="@f">
    @f
</div>
}
```

Comment: No, sadly it doesn't look like a name collision.

Comment: did you try my sample ? it works for me, but then I rename "f" variable to "format" it does not anymore

Comment: Yeah, I tried it, but it didn't work. Are you using Play 2.2.0? That's what I'm on. Maybe I'm having some weird library issues or something. I'll try again later this evening when I get home.